# Inferring/casting generic type to concrete type

Tags: scala, type-erasure

When I attempt to compile :

```
package com

object typeparam extends App {

  new MyClass[Int]().f2(3)

  class MyClass[B] {

    def f2(b: B): B = {
      b + b
    }

  }

}
```

I receive compiler error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : B
[error]  required: String
[error]       b + b
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
```

Why is b not inferred to an Int, as when I invoke the class I use the type parameter Int ?

If I instead use :

```
package com

object typeparam extends App {

  println(new MyClass[Int]().f2(3) * 3)

  class MyClass[B] {

    def f2(b: B): B = {
      b
    }

  }

}
```

The value 9 is correctly printed. So it seems the Int type is correctly inferred.

Is this related to type erasure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with type erasure. Your type parameter `B` is unbounded, and not every type has a `+` method. But every type can be implicitly converted to `String` in order to use the `+` method (inferred as `Any`), and that's exactly what's happening here.

Perhaps require the `Numeric` trait if you want this to only work with numbers?

```
class MyClass[B](implicit num: Numeric[B]) {
   def f2(b: B): B = num.plus(b, b)
}

scala> def myInst = new MyClass[Int]
myInst: MyClass[Int]

scala> myInst.f2(3)
res0: Int = 6
```

Comment: thanks, numbers is fine in this case. So the use of "implicit num: Numeric[B]" binds "b" to be of type Int ?

Comment: It's adding a constraint: the compiler won't let you instantiate MyClass unless B is a numeric type (which actually means that there is an implicit instance of Numeric[B] available).